# backbone js model parse function with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-model

Im fairly new to backbone and running into a weird problem

I have a model that looks like so:

```
 define( function ( require, exports, module )
 {
     "use strict";

var Backbone = require( 'backbone' );

return Backbone.Model.extend(
    {

        defaults: {
            isLoggedin: false
        },

        url: 'http://api.com/login',

        parse: function( data ){
            //do stuff based on call

        },
        initialize: function(){


        },
        doLogin: function( data ){

            this.fetch({
                data: data,
                type: 'POST'
            });

            this.isUserLoggedIn();
        },

        isUserLoggedIn: function(){

            this.fetch({
                url:'http://api.com/loggedIn',
                type: 'GET'
            });
        }

       doLogout: function () {

            this.fetch({
                url:'http://api.com/logout',
                type: 'POST'

                });


         }

    });
} );
```

As you can see i have 3 different functions happening what i need to do is based on the function i need to do different actions or return different results but with having one parse function how can i know which function is being called to do whatever i need in the parse. For example if isUserLoggedIn function is called i need to redirect them to some page based on response if doLogout is called i need to redirect them to another page based on response. Any ideas?

Comment: You can set another attr state to remember what's the last called function, or you can let the api to return some value to tell you which function call it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that as i mentioned im new to backbone and js

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the last called function like this:

```
return Backbone.Model.extend(
{

    defaults: {
        isLoggedin: false
    },

    url: 'http://api.com/login',

    parse: function( data ){
        if(this.lastCall == 'doLogin'){
            //do staff if doLogin was called
            this.isUserLoggedIn();
        }
        if(this.lastCall == 'isUserLoggedIn'){
            //do staff if isUserLoggedIn was called
        }
        if(this.lastCall == 'doLogout'){
            //do staff if doLogout was called
        }

    },
    initialize: function(){


    },
    doLogin: function( data ){
        this.lastCall = 'doLogin';
        this.fetch({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST'
        });


    },

    isUserLoggedIn: function(){
        this.lastCall = 'isUserLoggedIn';
        this.fetch({
            url:'http://api.com/loggedIn',
            type: 'GET'
        });
    }

   doLogout: function () {
        this.lastCall = 'doLogout';
        this.fetch({
            url:'http://api.com/logout',
            type: 'POST'

            });


     }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use second argument of the parse, that contain options.

```
MY_CONST = {
  SOME_KIND_OF_URL: '/api/prod'
}

if (dev) {
  MY_CONST.SOME_KIND_OF_URL = '/api/foo';
}

MyModel = Bacbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(response, options) {
    if (options.url === MY_CONST.SOME_KIND_OF_URL) {
  return 'foo';
    }
  }
},  MY_CONST)
```

Comment: If i use options i get the url of which call was made however i will have problems when i have a dev and production version of the api call. I know i can regex it and get the last parameter but that just seems too dirty

Comment: You can use some kind of constants, that override for prod/dev. And use them in your parse method aswell.